# How to force Magento2 admin category form to submit value of unchanged fields

Tags: magento, magento2

I am a new to Magento2 development, hope I am not asking some stupid questions.

I have created a custom table and add those fields into Magento2 admin category form, I find that if I haven't changed their value and click save, the fields value are not submitted, thus I get empty value for all these fields in Observer.

Is there anyway I can force Magento2 to submit these fields value even if it is unchanged? Thank you.

Comment: Highly appreciated if anyone can help me on this orz

Comment: can you add your code which you are trying with?